# Dumping object to files with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pickle, dump

I am trying to speed up my program by caching processed data in flutter.

I saved a book in html format inside assets directory, then I parsed the html book into a tree object. Unfortunately the book is quite big, so it took almost 5 seconds for parsing. I am thinking if I can cache that tree object, my program will be a lot faster. I know that in python, you can use the pickle object. In C++, you can just dump the object to file, but how do you do it with dart?

Original code

```
// tree = heavyParsing(htmlBook);
```

Now I want something like

```
// if processedTreeFile exist
// tree = read from processedTreeFile
// else 
// tree = heavyParsing(htmlBook)
// dump tree to processedTreeFile
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files for writing it to a file.

Comment: The file object in Flutter let you write string and bytes. If I can cast the object into bytes, then it will be helpful.

Comment: May I know the type of the tree object? I am not sure but you could just covert it to json.

Comment: TreeNode has children, and parent. Children is a list of treenode and parent is a treenode . It also has a title which is a string. Thank you . Json may work if it is string only

Comment: So is it a `Map` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Map-class.html?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it. Here is the class. 
class TreeNode {
  TreeNode parent;
  String tag;
  String text;
  List<TreeNode> children = [];
}

Comment: It is fairly straightforward to covert you class to a `Map` which can be then be json encoded with `json.encode()`.

Comment: Even if I dump it to json, when I reload the data, I need to parse that json file back to this tree / graph structure. Right now what I am doing is parsing xml to this tree structure . So reading and loading to json will not be any faster